# onActivityResult() is called to early for Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION

Tags: android, android-activity, android-preferences, android-permissions

I want to request the Overlay permission for my app to draw on top of other apps. For this I use [ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION)

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION, Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1234);
```

This works well and shows the appropriate setting screen but `onActivityResult` is called when the setting activity is first shown and not when destroyed so I never get the permission in `onActivityResult`. Do I miss something ?

Comment: Try getting rid of `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`.

Comment: Yup, that was it ! Thanks. But I put this flag on purpose because I did not want my activity yo be brought back to the top which is the case now :-/

Comment: Maybe use `NO_HISTORY` for this?

Comment: `NO_HISTORY` does not help

Comment: It might be doable using [moveTaskToBack](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#moveTaskToBack(boolean)) to put back the activity to the background after it has been put to the foreground. It's going to be a lot of activity stopping/starting but that might actually work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are starting a new task. From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int,%20android.os.Bundle))

> [...] if the activity you are launching uses the singleTask launch mode, it will not run in your task and thus you will immediately receive a cancel result.

So it should work if you remove

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Still, I needed this flag for my activity to stay in the background. So it appears that what I exactly want to do is not possible.